# How to draw magnetic lines of force in coil with Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw the magnetic lines of force in a coil that should looks like [this picture](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/imgmag/curloo.gif) using the `tikz` package. I've tried to use a `foreach loop` with controls but (maybe I'm placing the controls wrongly) I don't get ellipse like lines of force... The code I used is this one:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle arrowstyle=[scale=2] %Arrow size
    \draw[thick, black, postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position .42 with {\arrow[arrowstyle]{stealth}}}}] (0,0) ellipse (1 and 2);
    \foreach \x in {0,0.5,...,5}
        \draw (-3,\x) .. controls (0,0) and (0,0) .. (3,\x);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I think lines must be a part of an ellipse but I don't know how to place the inner point of these ellipses.

[image: Personnal try of drawing magnetic lines of force into a spire]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are better ways, polar plots e.g., but you can start with something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle arrowstyle=[scale=2] %Arrow size
    \draw[thick, black, postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position .42 with {\arrow[arrowstyle]{stealth}}}}] (0,0) ellipse (1 and 2);
    \path[clip] (-2,-2.7) rectangle (2,2.7);
    \foreach \y in {15,30,...,75} {
        \draw (0,{2*tan(\y)+1.5*cos(\y)}) ellipse ({1.5*tan(\y)} and {2*tan(\y)});
        \draw (0,{-2*tan(\y)-1.5*cos(\y)}) ellipse ({1.5*tan(\y)} and {2*tan(\y)});
    }
    \draw (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]